# iPhone4s locked due to "find my iphone"

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I have given my IPhone 4s to my niece. I have restored the phone to factory settings before giving it to her now we are trying to set it up and it is asking for my log in details for find my iphone. As I have not used the phone for months now I don't know these details and it does not have a forgot password option. Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your Apple ID password by going here:
https://iforgot.apple.com/

Also, make sure when you setup the phone again that your niece uses her own Apple ID and not yours.